# Prove inequality for vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

Let $\left\{ y_{1},...,y_{n}\right\} \subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

I wish to prove that:
$\left\Vert \sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(-1\right)^{j}y_{j}\right\Vert ^{2}\leq\frac{n\left(n+1\right)}{2}\cdot\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left\Vert y_{j}\right\Vert ^{2}$

What I'ved tried so far:

Defining $v=y_{1}+y_{3}+...+y_{n-1},\,u=y_{2}+y_{4}+...+y_{n}$ and then use the fact $\left\Vert u-v\right\Vert ^{2}=2\left(\left\Vert u\right\Vert ^{2}+\left\Vert v\right\Vert ^{2}\right)-\left\Vert u+v\right\Vert ^{2}$. Also I'ved tried to prove by induction, and of course using  triangle inequality.

Comment: Note that you can replace $y_{2n+1}$ by $-y_{2n+1}$, which gets rid of the $-1$ in the LHS and does not change the RHS

Comment: Do you know the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality?

Comment: Yes I know Cauchy-Schwartz inequality and I understand your comment about the replace of  $y_{2n+1}$ by -$y_{2n+1}$. So is enough to prove the inequality without $\left(-1\right)^{j}$. I wonder why then in the question they ask to prove this form of inequality. Anyway, I still can't see the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left\| \sum_{j=1}^n y_j\right\|^2
\le \left(\sum_{j=1}^n\|y_j\|\right)^2
\le \left(\sum_{j=1}^n 1\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^n \|y_j\|^2\right) 
= n\sum_{j=1}^n \|y_j\|^2\le \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\sum_{j=1}^n \|y_j\|^2$$